# column-count and keep with next in HTML / CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a two column design with a  structure e.g.

```
<div style="-webkit-column-count:2;-moz-column-count:2;column-count:2">
<dl>
 <dt>Category A</dt>
   <dd>Item A1</dd>
   <dd>Item A2</dd>
   <dd>Item A3</dd>
 <dt>Category B</dt>
 -------- here goes the automatic column switch with css [-webkit-|-moz-]column-count:2
   <dd>Item B2</dd>
   <dd>Item B3</dd>
 <dt>Category C</dt>
   <dd>Item C1</dd>
   <dd>Item C2</dd>
</dl>
</div>
```

In the above example the Category B should go on top of the second column.

Is it possible somehow to make sure that a `<dt>Categry</dt>` always has at least one `<dd>Item</dd>` below?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible with the single definition list as markup.

You just need to make sure that the height of your `dt` elements are at least double the current `line-height`, e.g. with `padding-bottom`, and that any `dd` element that follows a `dt` has a negative `top-margin` to compensate for the padding applied to the `dt`.  Then use `break-inside: avoid;` to prevent the browser from breaking within your `dt` element.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/8tqgw1wx/2/

Relevant CSS:

```
dt {
  padding-bottom:1.2em; /* Must match your line-height */
  break-inside: avoid;
}
dt + dd {
  margin-top:-1.2em; /* Must match your line-height */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there is no way to solve my problem with the current markup. But I found a reasonable solution using tables having just one cell.

Such a table is being treated as one block that cannot be split. I don't have that many `<dd>` items per `<dt>` category, so I can live with the output. Since the whole page is being generated from a database query it's an okay solution for me doing this with a template language which generates output like this:

```
<div style="-webkit-column-count:2;-moz-column-count:2;column-count:2">

<table><tr><td><dl>
 <dt>Category A</dt>
   <dd>Item A1</dd>
   <dd>Item A2</dd>
   <dd>Item A3</dd>
 </dt>
</dl></td></tr></table>

<table><tr><td><dl>
 <dt>Category B</dt>
   <dd>Item B2</dd>
   <dd>Item B3</dd>
</dl></td></tr></table>

<table><tr><td><dl>
 <dt>Category C</dt>
   <dd>Item C1</dd>
   <dd>Item C2</dd>
</dl></td></tr></table>

</div>
```

Comment: Why not use a div instead of a one cell table?

Comment: Because a div may be split up.